# Pandas rename columns does not rename the column

Tags: pandas

I tried to do this:

```
districtident.rename(columns={'leaid':'nces'},inplace=True)
```

and it failed:
[image]

Other things that didn't work:

```
districtident = districtident.rename(columns={'leaid':'nces'})
```

[Renaming the column names of pandas dataframe is not working as expected - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47060980/renaming-the-column-names-of-pandas-dataframe-is-not-working-as-expected-pytho)

[renaming columns in pandas doesn't do anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64206205/renaming-column-in-pandas-doesnt-do-anything)

Wasn't great either.

Here's an obvious appeal:

[image: obvious appeal]

Alas, no.

Restarting the kernel didnt' work either.  The only thing that worked was:

```
districtident['nces'] = districtident['leaid']
disrictident.drop(['leaid'],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

But that's really not the best, I feel.  Especially if I need to do a number of columns.

Comment: please post a sample of the `districtident` df. Copy paste it in the question and format as code. Avoid posting images of the data

Comment: I tried your data frame with fake data and the same names of columns and I renamed it. It works! I suggest posting a data frame itself in your question to see if there is any hidden problem.

Comment: Do you get anything with `errors="raise"` in your rename call?

Comment: And have you got duplicate column names at all? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774787/renaming-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe-with-duplicate-column-names

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem with one specific DF after I concatenated a Pandas DF with two Pandas Series. Tried to use several variants of `df.rename()` listed below. None of them worked.

```
# using column name and axis 
df = df.rename({'oldName1':'newName1', 'oldName2':'newName2'}, axis = 'columns')

# using column index and axis
df = df.rename({28:'newName1', 29:'newName2'}, axis = 'columns')

# using column name
df = df.rename(columns = {'oldName1':'newName1', 'oldName2':'newName2'})

# using column name and inplace function
df.rename(columns = {'oldName1':'newName1', 'oldName2':'newName2'}, inplace = True)

# using column index and inplace function
df.rename(columns = {28:'newName1', 29:'newName2'}, inplace = True)
```

Also tried [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49429646/rename-column-in-pandas-python-not-working/76719778#76719778) `df.rename(columns={(28, 'newName1'): 'newName1'}, inplace = True`, which did not work.

What worked is this:
`df.columns.values[27]= 'newName1'`  
This is of course not ideal as it needs to be done individually for each column. As I only had 2 columns to rename this is ok for me. If possible I recommend to use `df.rename()`, but if it just doesn't work this may be an alternative.